# I cant access internet in avd's below 3.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.1

Help - I couldn't use internet in my emulator. I m in a corporate network. Even after giving my proxy settings in telkilla APN, i couldnt able to access the network.
However if i try to access internet in AVD's above 3.0, its reachable.

Kindly anyone help in clearing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem. put this after setContentView(r.layout.main)

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","your_proxy");

System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","8080");